# PHP reading "Unicode" MS Word doc

Tags: php, unicode, ms-word, unicode-string

I''m trying to read some Ms Word Doc in PHP which is in Unicode, some stuff like Hebrew or Arabic. but it reads in binary and turns into some non scenes chars. I googled up some  sample codes but non of those worked properly, do you have any experience in Unicode docs like Arabic and Hebrew? thanks

Comment: Did you even parse the Word document as a Word document? The Arabic unicode block is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_(Unicode_block) If you got a decent Unicode implementation, I don't see why handling arabic or hebrew would be any different from other character ranges.

Comment: Did you write your own MS Word implementation from scratch??

Comment: @Y sangkok, yes I parsed it, but couldn't go trough.

Comment: @ePezhman scratch, n: base, the beginning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the drawbacks of PHP is that (at least until recently) has been Unicode-ignorant. You usually get along with this by simply ignoring the fact that what you are reading is Unicode and hoping that the web browser your document ends up in knows how to deal with Unicode. PHP doesn't destroy anything, it just doesn't care.

Depending on what you are trying to do, there are a few additions to PHP that allow improved Unicode handling. Among them are the `mb_` string functions, which cope with multi-byte strings.

You also need to find out how the text is encoded in the Word document. Unicode supports many formats, the most popular and most compact one being `UTF-8`, yet there are also `UTF-16` and `UTF-32`.

Comment: *Most compact* depends largely on what content you have, it's not a general truth that UTF-8 is most compact; only for text that is mostly ASCII. However, UTF-32 is always least compact.

Comment: @Fabian thanks for answer, do you think it's possible to convert binary to utf-8?